# PHP Error: Call to Undefined Function

Tags: php

I have two methods in a PHP class:

```
    public static function sID($urlID) {
            return base_convert($urlID, 10, 62) - 239000;
    }

    public static function load($urlID) {
            if ($urlID = "" || !is_numeric($urlID)) return 0;
            $id = sID($urlID); // ERROR ON THIS LINE
    }
```

I am getting the error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function sID()

I have looked around online but amazingly enough, haven't found any solution to this seemingly simple problem.  Is there a syntax error or otherwise?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a [static class method](http://www.php.net/static), so you have to reference it with `self::`.

```
$id = self::sID($urlID);
```

You can also use the class name: (here, assuming `class Foo`):

```
$id = Foo::sID($urlID);
```

Since you're doing this within the class itself, using `self::` is probably cleaner and easier to understand.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you haven't declared a `sID()` function, you declared a static method. Which can be called with `className::sID()` (or `self::sID()` from inside the class itself).